# d3.js eyes following mouse blocks

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to create 2 d3.js&svg eyes that follow mouse cursor with pupils and when the mouse come over them they move in a random position. However, after a random number of succesfull movements they freeze, and i can not understand why.

This is the code:

```
var width = 1200,
    height = 600;

var ptdata = [];

var pray = 10, 
    eray = 50;

var cx0 = 0, cx1 = 100
    cy = 0;

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g");

var eye0 = svg.append("circle")
.attr("id", "eye0")
.attr("class", "eye")
.attr("cx", cx0)
.attr("cy", cy)
.attr("r", eray)
.attr("stroke", "black")
.attr("fill", "white")
.data([ptdata]);

var eye1 = svg.append("circle")
.attr("id", "eye1")
.attr("class", "eye")
.attr("cx", cx1)
.attr("cy", cy)
.attr("r", eray)
.attr("stroke", "black")
.attr("fill", "white")
.data([ptdata]);

var pupil0 = svg.append("circle")
.attr("id", "pupil0")
.attr("class", "pupil")
.attr("cx", cx0)
.attr("cy", cy)
.attr("r", pray)
.attr("fill", "black")
.data([ptdata]);

var pupil1 = svg.append("circle")
.attr("id", "pupil1")
.attr("class", "pupil")
.attr("cx", cx1)
.attr("cy", cy)
.attr("r", pray)
.attr("fill", "black")
.data([ptdata]);

var eyes = svg.selectAll(".eye");
var pupils = svg.selectAll(".pupil");

function init() {
    var tx0 = 0, ty0 = 0;
    while (tx0<eray || (tx0+cx1)>(width-eray)) {
        var randx = Math.round(Math.random() * width, 2);
        tx0 = randx;
    }
    while (ty0<eray || (ty0+cy)>(height-eray)) {
        var randy = Math.round(Math.random() * height, 2);
        ty0 = randy;
    }

    cx0 += tx0; cx1 += tx0; cy += ty0;
    eye0.attr("cx", cx0);
    eye1.attr("cx", cx1);
    eyes.attr("cy", cy);
    pupil0.attr("cx", cx0);
    pupil1.attr("cx", cx1);
    pupils.attr("cy", cy);
}   
init();

var distanceThreshold = eray - pray;

var mouseX = cx0, mouseY = cy;

var svgagain = d3.select("body").select("svg")
.on("mousemove", function() { 
    var pt = d3.mouse(this); 
    follow(pt); 
});

function follow(pt) {
    ptdata.push(pt);

    var x = pt[0];
    var y = pt[1];

    var d0 = {
        dx: x - cx0,
        dy: y - cy
    };
    var distance0 = Math.sqrt(d0.dx * d0.dx + d0.dy * d0.dy);

    var d1 = {
        dx: x - cx1,
        dy: y - cy
    };
    var distance1 = Math.sqrt(d1.dx * d1.dx + d1.dy * d1.dy);

    mouseX0 = d0.dx / distance0 * distanceThreshold + cx0;
    mouseY0 = d0.dy / distance0 * distanceThreshold + cy;

    var xp0 = cx0, yp0 = cy;
    var xp1 = cx1, yp1 = cy;

    pupil0.attr("cx", 
        function(d) { 
            xp0 += (mouseX0 - xp0) / 1;
            return xp0; 
        })
    .attr("cy", 
        function(d) { 
            yp0 += (mouseY0 - yp0) / 1;
            return yp0; 
        });

    mouseX1 = d1.dx / distance1 * distanceThreshold + cx1;
    mouseY1 = d1.dy / distance1 * distanceThreshold + cy;


    pupil1.attr("cx", 
        function(d) { 
            xp1 += (mouseX1 - xp1) / 1;
            return xp1; 
        })
    .attr("cy", 
        function(d) { 
            yp1 += (mouseY1 - yp1) / 1;
            return yp1; 
        });
}

function move(pt) {
    ptdata.push(pt);

    var x = pt[0];
    var y = pt[1];

    var tx = 0, ty = 0;
    var newCX0 = cx0, newCX1 = cx1, newCY = cy;
    while (x<(newCX1+eray) && x>(newCX0-eray) && y<(newCY+eray) && y>(newCY-eray) ||
        (newCX0<eray || newCX1>(width-eray) || newCY<eray || newCY>(height-eray))){
        var randx = Math.round(Math.random() * width, 2);
        tx = Math.random() < 0.5 ? (-randx) : randx;
        newCX0 += tx; newCX1 += tx;
        var randy = Math.round(Math.random() * height, 2);
        ty = Math.random() < 0.5 ? (-randy) : randy;
        newCY += ty;
    }

    cx0 = newCX0; cx1 = newCX1; cy = newCY;
    eye0.attr("cx", cx0);
    eye1.attr("cx", cx1);
    eyes.attr("cy", cy);
    pupil0.attr("cx", cx0);
    pupil1.attr("cx", cx1);
    pupils.attr("cy", cy);
}

var eye0again = eye0.on("mouseover", function() { 
    var pt = d3.mouse(this); 
    move(pt); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved in this way:

```
function move(pt) {

    var x = pt[0];
    var y = pt[1];

    var newCX0 = cx0, newCX1 = cx1, newCY = cy;
    while (newCX0>(cx0-eray) && newCX0<(cx1+eray) && newCY>(cy-eray) && newCY<(cy+eray)) {
        var randx = Math.random()*(width-(eray*4)) + eray;
        newCX0 = Math.round(randx, 2);
        newCX1 = newCX0+(eray*2);
        var randy = Math.random()*(height-(eray*2)) + eray;
        newCY = Math.round(randy, 2);
    }

    cx0 = newCX0; cx1 = newCX1; cy = newCY;
    eye0
    .attr("cx", cx0);
    eye1
    .attr("cx", cx1);
    eyes
    .attr("cy", cy);

    pupil0
    .attr("cx", cx0);
    pupil1
    .attr("cx", cx1);
    pupils
    .attr("cy", cy);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is getting stuck in the `while` loop in your `move` function.  The conditions in the `while` loop are not converging, since the eyes are moving over the page.

Try this:

```js
var width = 600,
  height = 300;

var ptdata = [];

var pray = 10,
  eray = 50;

var cx0 = 0,
  cx1 = 100,
  cy = 0;

var svg = d3.select("#vis")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g");

var eye0 = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("id", "eye0")
  .attr("class", "eye")
  .attr("cx", cx0)
  .attr("cy", cy)
  .attr("r", eray)
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .data([ptdata]);

var eye1 = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("id", "eye1")
  .attr("class", "eye")
  .attr("cx", cx1)
  .attr("cy", cy)
  .attr("r", eray)
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .data([ptdata]);

var pupil0 = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("id", "pupil0")
  .attr("class", "pupil")
  .attr("cx", cx0)
  .attr("cy", cy)
  .attr("r", pray)
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .data([ptdata]);

var pupil1 = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("id", "pupil1")
  .attr("class", "pupil")
  .attr("cx", cx1)
  .attr("cy", cy)
  .attr("r", pray)
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .data([ptdata]);

var eyes = svg.selectAll(".eye");
var pupils = svg.selectAll(".pupil");

function init() {
  var tx0 = 0,
    ty0 = 0;
  while (tx0 < eray || (tx0 + cx1) > (width - eray)) {
    var randx = Math.round(Math.random() * width, 2);
    tx0 = randx;
  }
  while (ty0 < eray || (ty0 + cy) > (height - eray)) {
    var randy = Math.round(Math.random() * height, 2);
    ty0 = randy;
  }

  cx0 += tx0;
  cx1 += tx0;
  cy += ty0;
  eye0.attr("cx", cx0);
  eye1.attr("cx", cx1);
  eyes.attr("cy", cy);
  pupil0.attr("cx", cx0);
  pupil1.attr("cx", cx1);
  pupils.attr("cy", cy);
}
init();

var distanceThreshold = eray - pray;

var mouseX = cx0,
  mouseY = cy;

var svgagain = d3.select("body").select("svg")
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    var pt = d3.mouse(this);
    follow(pt);
  });

function follow(pt) {
  ptdata.push(pt);

  var x = pt[0];
  var y = pt[1];

  var d0 = {
    dx: x - cx0,
    dy: y - cy
  };
  var distance0 = Math.sqrt(d0.dx * d0.dx + d0.dy * d0.dy);

  var d1 = {
    dx: x - cx1,
    dy: y - cy
  };
  var distance1 = Math.sqrt(d1.dx * d1.dx + d1.dy * d1.dy);

  mouseX0 = d0.dx / distance0 * distanceThreshold + cx0;
  mouseY0 = d0.dy / distance0 * distanceThreshold + cy;

  var xp0 = cx0,
    yp0 = cy;
  var xp1 = cx1,
    yp1 = cy;

  pupil0.attr("cx",
      function(d) {
        xp0 += (mouseX0 - xp0) / 1;
        return xp0;
      })
    .attr("cy",
      function(d) {
        yp0 += (mouseY0 - yp0) / 1;
        return yp0;
      });

  mouseX1 = d1.dx / distance1 * distanceThreshold + cx1;
  mouseY1 = d1.dy / distance1 * distanceThreshold + cy;


  pupil1.attr("cx",
      function(d) {
        xp1 += (mouseX1 - xp1) / 1;
        return xp1;
      })
    .attr("cy",
      function(d) {
        yp1 += (mouseY1 - yp1) / 1;
        return yp1;
      });
}

function move(pt) {
  ptdata.push(pt);

  var x = pt[0];
  var y = pt[1];

  var tx = 0,
    ty = 0;
  var newCX0 = cx0,
    newCX1 = cx1,
    newCY = cy;
  while (x < (newCX1 + eray) && x > (newCX0 - eray) && y < (newCY + eray) && y > (newCY - eray) ||
    (newCX0 < eray || newCX1 > (width - eray) || newCY < eray || newCY > (height - eray))) {
    var randx = Math.round(Math.random() * width, 2);
    tx = Math.random() < 0.5 ? (-randx) : randx;
    newCX0 += tx;
    newCX1 += tx;
    var randy = Math.round(Math.random() * height, 2);
    ty = Math.random() < 0.5 ? (-randy) : randy;
    newCY += ty;
  }

  cx0 = newCX0;
  cx1 = newCX1;
  cy = newCY;
  //    eye0.attr("cx", cx0);
  //    eye1.attr("cx", cx1);
  //    eyes.attr("cy", cy);
  pupil0.attr("cx", cx0);
  pupil1.attr("cx", cx1);
  pupils.attr("cy", cy);
}

/*
var eye0again = eye0.on("mouseover", function() { 
    var pt = d3.mouse(this); 
    move(pt); 
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="vis"></div>
```

I've commented out a couple of sections which will stop the behaviour that you were seeing.  The bits I've commented out were causing the eyes to jump around the svg.  At some point, the position they ended up in were causing your `move` function to get stuck in the while loop, as mentioned above.  By stopping the jumping the `while` loop seems to terminate correctly.

Comment: in your demo they don't move.

Comment: They do for me... which browser are you using?

Comment: It's working in chrome for me, not sure what your issue with it is.  You are moving your mouse over the SVG element, right?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an old script I wrote in 2001 and updated a year ago. Not exactly what you want but you should be able to transpose the 'eye math' .

```js
(function () {

    /* Following Eyes 2003 - kurt.grigg@yahoo.co.uk (Updated) */

    var eye = 50; //Eye size in pixels

    if (eye % 2 == 0){
        eye++;
    }
    var eye5 = eye / 2 | 0;
    var pup = 42 * eye / 100; 
    if (pup % 2 == 0){
        pup++;
    }
    var pup5 = (pup - 3) / 2;
    if (pup5 % 2 == 1){
        pup5++;
    }
    var grng = (eye - pup) / 2; 
    if (grng % 2 == 1){
        grng++;
    }
    var rng = eye5 / grng; 
    var d = document;
    var my = 0;
    var mx = 0;
    var fy = 0;
    var fx = 0;
    var ros = eye + 2;
    var scy = 0;
    var scx = 0;
    var mls = 1000 / 60;
    var lastEx = performance.now();
    var h, w, dy, dx, chy, chx, d1, d2, a1, a2, le, re, yec, xec;

    var cstyle =
        'position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:'+(ros*2)+'px;height:'+ros+'px;'
        +'margin:0px;border:none;padding:0px;display:inline-block;';

    var estyle =
        'position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;height:'+eye+'px;'
        +'width:'+eye+'px;background-color:#ffffff;'
        +'border-radius: 50%;border: 1px solid #000000;'
        +'box-shadow: inset -'+eye/3+'px -'+eye/3+'px '+eye/2+
        'px -'+(eye/10|0)+'px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);';

    var pstyle =
        'position:absolute;top:45%;left:45%;height:'+pup+'px;'
        +'width:'+pup+'px;background-color:#000000;border-radius: 50%;';

    var wstyle =
        'position:absolute;top:16%;left:16%;width:20%;height:20%;'
        +'background:#ffffff;border-radius:50%;'
        +'transform: skewX(-15deg) skewY(-18deg);';

    var c = d.createElement('div');
    var e1 = d.createElement('div');
    var e2 = d.createElement('div');
    var p1 = d.createElement('div');
    var p2 = d.createElement('div');
    var w1 = d.createElement('div');
    var w2 = d.createElement('div');

    c.setAttribute('style', cstyle);
    e1.setAttribute('style', estyle);
    e2.setAttribute('style', estyle + 'left:'+ros+'px;');
    p1.setAttribute('style', pstyle);
    p2.setAttribute('style', pstyle);
    w1.setAttribute('style', wstyle);
    w2.setAttribute('style', wstyle);

     d.body.appendChild(c);
    c.appendChild(e1);
    c.appendChild(e2);
    d.body.appendChild(p1);
    d.body.appendChild(p2);
    p1.appendChild(w1);
    p2.appendChild(w2);

    function scrl(v) {
        var y, x;
        y = window.pageYOffset;
        x = window.pageXOffset;
        return (v == 0) ? y : x;
    }

    function initscroll() {
        scy = scrl(0);
        scx = scrl(1);
    }

    function windims() {
        var tmp = d.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var ch = (typeof tmp == 'number');
        var sc = (ch) ? window.innerWidth - tmp : 0;
        h = window.innerHeight;
        w = window.innerWidth - sc;
    }

    function mouse(e) {
        if (!e) {
            e = window.event;
        }
        my = e.pageY - window.pageYOffset;
        mx = e.pageX - window.pageXOffset;
    }

    function ani() {
        //Keep eyes on screen.
        chy = Math.floor(fy - (ros*1.2));
        if (chy <= 0) {
            chy = 0;
        }
        if (chy >= h - ros) {
            chy = h - ros;
        }

        chx = Math.floor(fx - ros);
        if (chx <= 0) {
            chx = 0;
        }
        if (chx >= w - (ros*2)) {
            chx = w - (ros*2);
        }

        //Eyeball centres.
        yec = chy + eye5;
        xec = chx + eye5;

        d1 = Math.sqrt((my - yec) * (my - yec) + (mx - xec) * (mx - xec));
        d2 = Math.sqrt((my - yec) * (my - yec) + (mx - (xec + ros)) * (mx - (xec + ros)));

        a1 = Math.atan2(my - yec, mx - xec) * 180 / Math.PI;
        a2 = Math.atan2(my - yec, mx - (xec + ros)) * 180 / Math.PI;

        le = (d1 < eye5) ? d1 / rng : grng;
        re = (d2 < eye5) ? d2 / rng : grng;

        c.style.top = chy + scy + 'px';
        c.style.left = chx + scx + 'px';

        p1.style.top = yec - pup5 + le * Math.sin(a1 * Math.PI / 180) + scy + 'px';
        p1.style.left = xec - pup5 + le * Math.cos(a1 * Math.PI / 180) + scx + 'px';

        p2.style.top = yec - pup5 + re * Math.sin(a2 * Math.PI / 180) + scy + 'px';
        p2.style.left = (xec + ros) - pup5 + re * Math.cos(a2 * Math.PI / 180) + scx + 'px';
    }

    function move() {
        dy = fy += (my - fy) * 0.05;
        dx = fx += (mx - fx) * 0.05;
        ani();
    }

    function init() {
        windims();
        draw();
    }

    function draw() {
        var now = performance.now();
        if ((now - lastEx) > (mls)) {
            move();
            lastEx = performance.now();
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", windims, false);
    window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
    d.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse, false);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", initscroll, false);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find and jazz up my other old watching eyes script with out it following the mouse. It's easily resizeable and an in-line block so

```js
(function () {

    /* Watching Eyes 2001 - kurt.grigg@yahoo.co.uk (Updated) */

    var eye = 60; //Eye size in pixels

    if (eye % 2 == 0){
        eye++;
    }
    var eye5 = eye / 2 | 0;
    var pup = 42 * eye / 100; 
    if (pup % 2 == 0){
        pup++;
    }
    var pup5 = (pup - 1) / 2;
    if (pup5 % 2 == 1){
        pup5++;
    }
    var grng = (eye - pup) / 2; 
    if (grng % 2 == 1){
        grng++;
    }
    var rng = eye5 / grng; 
    var p1, p2, osy, osx, yec, xec, d1, d2, a1, a2, le, re;
    var ros = eye + 2;
    var pix = 'px';
    var d = document;

    var cstyle =
        'position:relative;width:'+(ros*2)+'px;height:'+ros+'px;'
        +'margin:0px;border:none;padding:0px;display:inline-block;';

    var estyle =
        'position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;height:'+eye+'px;'
        +'width:'+eye+'px;background-color:#ffffff;'
        +'border-radius: 50%;border: 1px solid #000000;'
        +'box-shadow: inset -'+eye/3+'px -'+eye/3+'px '+eye/2+
        'px -'+(eye/10|0)+'px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);';

    var pstyle =
        'position:absolute;top:45%;left:45%;height:'+pup+'px;'
        +'width:'+pup+'px;background-color:#000000;border-radius: 50%;';

    var wstyle =
        'position:absolute;top:16%;left:16%;width:20%;height:20%;'
        +'background:#ffffff;border-radius:50%;'
        +'transform: skewX(-15deg) skewY(-18deg);';

    var c = d.createElement('div');
    var e1 = d.createElement('div');
    var e2 = d.createElement('div');
    var p1 = d.createElement('div');
    var p2 = d.createElement('div');
    var w1 = d.createElement('div');
    var w2 = d.createElement('div');

    c.setAttribute('style', cstyle);
    e1.setAttribute('style', estyle);
    e2.setAttribute('style', estyle + 'left:'+ros+'px;');
    p1.setAttribute('style', pstyle);
    p2.setAttribute('style', pstyle);
    w1.setAttribute('style', wstyle);
    w2.setAttribute('style', wstyle);

    d.body.appendChild(c);
    c.appendChild(e1);
    c.appendChild(e2);
    e1.appendChild(p1);
    e2.appendChild(p2);
    p1.appendChild(w1);
    p2.appendChild(w2);

function ani(y, x) {
    osy = c.offsetTop;
    osx = c.offsetLeft;

    yec = osy + eye5;
    xec = osx + eye5;

    d1 = Math.sqrt((y - yec) * (y - yec) + (x - xec) * (x - xec));
    d2 = Math.sqrt((y - yec) * (y - yec) + (x - (xec + ros)) * (x - (xec + ros)));
    a1 = Math.atan2(y - yec, x - xec) * 180 / Math.PI;
    a2 = Math.atan2(y - yec, x - (xec + ros)) * 180 / Math.PI;

    le = (d1 < eye5) ? d1 / rng : grng;
    re = (d2 < eye5) ? d2 / rng : grng;

    p1.style.top = yec - pup5 + le * Math.sin(a1 * Math.PI / 180) - osy + pix;
    p1.style.left = xec - pup5 + le * Math.cos(a1 * Math.PI / 180) - osx + pix;

    p2.style.top = yec - pup5 + re * Math.sin(a2 * Math.PI / 180) - osy + pix;
    p2.style.left = (xec) - pup5 + re * Math.cos(a2 * Math.PI / 180) - osx + pix;
}

function mouse(e) {
    var y, x;
    if (!e) {
        e = window.event;
    }
    y = e.pageY - 1;
    x = e.pageX - 1;
    ani(y, x);
}

d.addEventListener("mousemove",mouse,false);

})();
```

can be placed neatly among the HTML flow.